# XSL code coverage tool

Tags: xslt, code-coverage

Are there any tools that can tell me what percentage of a XSL document get actually executed during tests?

**UPDATE**

I could not find anything better than Oxygen's XSL debugger and profiler, so I'm accepting Mladen's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about code coverage itself, but you can find an [XML debugger and profiler from Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_debugger.html) which might help you out.

Answer (score 11):

This didn't exist back when this question was asked, but now there is ONE option for finding code coverage of XSLT documents:

http://code.google.com/p/cakupan/

I'll admit that I haven't used it yet, as I'm still gathering information right now, but as far as I'm aware, this is IT.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, Saxon has a [performance analysis](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html), which has a functionality that gives you a breakdown of each template and the number of times they are used (which is great for optimisation).

This is how my output looks like:

[image]